# Solution of $a x+\sin x -L =0$

Tags: real-analysis

How to find $x$ such that $a x+\sin x -L =0$ where $L,a$ are constant and $a>0$?

Thank you .

Comment: In general, you can not solve this equation in a closed form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This type of equations are called [Transcendental equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_equation) and are generally not solvable in a closed form. However, you can use numerical techniques like [Newton-Raphson method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method), [Bisection method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method) etc to find out the solution very accurately.

Comment: please , i want to find a bound B such that the intersection between $\sin x$ and $-ax+L$ are included in $[-B,B]$ how to do please ? thank you.

Comment: From $|\sin x|\le 1$ you get $\frac{L-1}{a}\le x_0\le \frac{L+1}{a} $ where $x_0$ is the point of intersection of the two curves. I think, this is a good interval to start with.

Comment: so $B=\frac{L+1}{a}$ ? thank you

Comment: If your $L\ge 1$ you need not consider -ve lower bound.

Comment: i have any nothing about $L$

Comment: Then you can just start with $\displaystyle B=\frac{L+1}{a}$ Evntually you'll get very close to the exact solution if you employ any of those methods.